# Is there a good way to tell when Aiden can open a door?

Tags: watch-dogs

Some doors in Watch Dogs are just scenery. Others can be opened. Is there some visual clue to guide you towards which is which?

For example, in L.A. Noire, gold doorknobs indicated openable doors, while gray knobs could not be used.

Comment: It's frustrating. A lot of doors/gates have glowing blue lights on them to show unlocked, or red to show locked. But last night I was searching for a sneaky shortcut in a mission where they wanted me to kill everyone. I didn't want to kill everyone and I found a door that looked like scenery, but wasn't, and lead almost directly to the exit point. A bit frustrating.

Comment: The usable doord have higher resolution when you play with low video settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The best way is to just try and open it.